# Checking for a hashtag in c++ array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to count how many of a certain hashtag I have in my array of tweets. I am getting crazy numbers. This is my code:

```
// returns the number of tweets with the given hashtag
int MicroBlog::GetNumHashtag(const string Hashtag)
{
   string Choice;
   int NumHashtag;

   cout << "Which hashtag would you like to check for in the tweets? " << endl;
   cin >> Choice;
   cout << "The hashtag you have chosen is: " << Choice << endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TWEETS; i++)
   {
      if (blog[i].GetHashtag() == Choice)
         NumHashtag++;
   }
   cout << "There are " << NumHashtag << " hashtags in the blog. " << endl;
   return NumHashtag;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
int NumHashtag;
```

leads to *undefined behavior*.

This includes random numbers located in the memory object assigned to `NumHashtag`. The only thing you have to do is to initialize the object:

```
int NumHashtag = 0;
```